# How to return the same content for any path base on User Agent?

Tags: apache2, server-administration

I run a server with the URL pattern `http://*.self/`.  Based on the client's User Agent string i need to return the same content whatever their path may be.  In example:

- http://example.self/foo
- http://example.self/bar
- http://example.self/asdf

Will return this exact same content by `/path/to/search-bot/index.php`:

```
<body>
  <h1>Thou sahll not!</h1>
</body>
```

Here is my apache VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName self
  ServerAlias *.self
  VirtualDocumentRoot /some/path
</VitualHost>
```

The following...

```
  BrowserMatch "(?i:Googlebot)" no_bot=1 #google
  <If "reqenv('no_bot') == 1">
    AliasMatch .* /path/to/search-bot/index.php
  </If>
```

...gives me this error after running `service apache2 restart`:

```
AliasMatch not allowed here
```

**EDIT**

For the issue about [Clocking for Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en), yes, i understand, but i **DO** intend to get penalized by Google.  I have special reason to.

Comment: google really does not like it if you serve it different content to users. make sure your doing this for a real good reason

Comment: "Cloaking refers to the practice of presenting different content or URLs to human users and search engines. Cloaking is considered a violation of Google’s Webmaster Guidelines because it provides our users with different results than they expected."

Comment: Hi i understand what you mean, do not worry i know what i am doing. And i do have special reasons for it, as in, i intent to get blocked by Google.